# sed/awk: replace megabytes with bytes (insert zeros)

Tags: regex, bash, csv, awk, sed

I have .csv file which fields are delimited with comma, rows by \n .
In some rows I have megabytes symbol. I'd like to replace it with zeros to have (more or less) correct size in bytes.

What I have is

**,2.6 M,**

and I'd like to have

**,2600000,**

**Example**

```
2015-06-01 00:04:52.736,10.0.0.2,10.0.0.4,443,443,56923,2.6 M,10.156.119.1
2015-06-01 00:04:56.736,10.0.0.2,10.0.0.4,443,58935,55658,1.3 M,10.156.126.1
2015-06-01 00:04:56.736,10.0.0.2,10.0.0.4,443,86,54801,1256,10.156.119.1
2015-06-01 00:04:52.736,10.0.0.2,10.0.0.4,443,49652,443,1.6 M,10.156.119.1
2015-06-01 00:04:53.732,10.0.0.2,10.0.0.4,443,443,55770,4.9 M,10.156.119.1
2015-06-01 00:04:54.732,10.0.0.2,10.0.0.4,443,80,45980,639,10.156.119.1
2015-06-01 00:04:54.732,10.0.0.2,10.0.0.4,443,63951,27058,1.2 M,10.156.119.1
2015-06-01 00:04:54.732,10.0.0.2,10.0.0.4,443,80,41035,13.8 M,10.156.119.1
2015-06-01 00:04:55.736,10.0.0.2,10.0.0.4,443,80,40078,7.9 M,10.156.119.1
2015-06-01 00:04:56.732,10.0.0.2,10.0.0.4,443,42008,4.5 M,10.156.119.1
```

**Target**

```
2015-06-01 00:04:52.736,10.0.0.2,10.0.0.4,443,443,56923,2600000,10.156.119.1
2015-06-01 00:04:56.736,10.0.0.2,10.0.0.4,443,58935,55658,1300000,10.156.126.1
2015-06-01 00:04:56.736,10.0.0.2,10.0.0.4,443,86,54801,1256,10.156.119.1
2015-06-01 00:04:52.736,10.0.0.2,10.0.0.4,443,49652,443,1600000,10.156.119.1
2015-06-01 00:04:53.732,10.0.0.2,10.0.0.4,443,443,55770,4900000,10.156.119.1
2015-06-01 00:04:54.732,10.0.0.2,10.0.0.4,443,80,45980,639,10.156.119.1
2015-06-01 00:04:54.732,10.0.0.2,10.0.0.4,443,63951,27058,1200000,10.156.119.1
2015-06-01 00:04:54.732,10.0.0.2,10.0.0.4,443,80,41035,13800000 M,10.156.119.1
2015-06-01 00:04:55.736,10.0.0.2,10.0.0.4,443,80,40078,7900000,10.156.119.1
2015-06-01 00:04:56.732,10.0.0.2,10.0.0.4,443,42008,4500000,10.156.119.1
```

Comment: shouldn't the correct multiple be 1024*1024?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed 's/\([0-9]*\)\.\([0-9]*\) M/\1\200000/' file
```

Comment: Where does the number 200000 come from?

Comment: @t_thirupathi it is `\2` then 5 `0`s

Comment: @Marcaitus, this works only if there's exactly one digit after the decimal point.

Comment: @bro, it does match and give an output, but the output is wrong. It simply removes the decimal point and appends 5 `0`s all the time.

Comment: @t_thirupathi, ok. that's true. I didn't get what you meant. ;)

Comment: simply assume entry are 1 digit after dot like sample show

Answer (score 3):

This is complicated by the last line in your sample data missing a column.

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} {$(NF-1)=$(NF-1)*1000000} 1' file
```

If sometimes you have "M", sometimes "K", we can accomodate that:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
      FS=OFS=","
      mult[""]=1
      mult["K"]=1000
      mult["M"]=1000000
      mult["G"]=1000000000
    } 
    {
      split($(NF-1), a, " ")
      $(NF-1) = a[1] * mult[a[2]]
      print
    }
'
```

Comment: one note here...
mathematical multiplying may give you unwanted result depending on the engine of your db system. e.g. for me from 2.6 M it gave 2.6 e^6 :)

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/ \([KMG]\)/000000000\1/
     s/\.\([0-9]\{3\}[0-9]*K/\1/
     s/\.\([0-9]\{6\}[0-9]*M/\1/
     s/\.\([0-9]\{9\}[0-9]*G/\1/
    ' YourFile
```

- Based on your sample where there is only number with 1 letter for multiple of 1000 unit that we should change

could be simplified using `sed 's/\.\([^,]*\) M/\1000000/' YourFile` if only M occur like in your sample (1 digit only after a dot for value using a M)